# Enabling org/user level rate limiting in K8S Istio Ingress using Envoy filter

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

Is there any way to configure org/user level rate limiting using K8S Istio Ingress?

Currently I have rate limiting enabled at microservice level for API calls. I'm looking for the option to do it using Envoy filter. Can anyone share the way to do it.

Thanks for you help.

[https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#:~:text=Envoy%20supports%20two%20kinds%20of,of%20requests%20per%20service%20instance](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#:%7E:text=Envoy%20supports%20two%20kinds%20of,of%20requests%20per%20service%20instance).

I tried above documentation, but it is not way for org/user level rate limiting.